# Upload file with selenium and python using ubuntu

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, file-upload, selenium-webdriver

I have this problem, I need to upload a file using selenium webdriver and Python i'm working on ubuntu. I already saw a lot of answer of this question but not working for me. The HTML of the button is similar to this:

```
<button class="classes">Update button</button>
```

That's all.

So if you see here there no exist type=file in the html.

And I tried the 'send_keys' to the button something like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_id('file_name').send_keys(file_path)
```

Also I tried with JS using:

```
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('filename').value='" + file_path + "';")
```

So my question is, there is another way to upload the file? Or i'm doing something wrong?

I will appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Could you post a little bit more HTML (e.g. the whole `<form>` or whatever is around the button) and maybe a screen shot of the page you're trying to automate?

Comment: Just a question, in the execute_script the 'fileName' is the Id of the element?